# Layering canvas objects on JPEG's - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, overlapping, maze

I am creating a **maze game** and so far have rendered a circle which the player will move and loaded a Maze jpeg.
When the two overlap the circle is hidden by the JPEG, **what is the method which allows two objects to be overlapped?**

Question 2 
I have created a 10 x 10 table with cell ID's from 1 - 100 and put these values in an array. For my game I need to check the ID of the square the player wants to progress to and see if they can go there. Would I use a **hash table lookup** or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1:**

The last drawn object is always on top, so draw your maze first and your player second.

**Question #2:**

It might be easier to lay out your cells in a 2-dimensional array:

```
// note: these example numbers do not form a valid maze :-)

var maze=[
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
];
```

...And define your character's position as an x,y coordinate:

```
var playerX=5;
var playerY=5;
```

Then you can examine each cell neighboring the player like this:

```
var north=maze[ playerX,   playerY-1 ];
var south=maze[ playerX,   playerY+1 ];
var east=maze[  playerX+1, playerY ];
var west=maze[  playerX-1, playerY ];
```

...And allow/disallow moves accordingly.

But if you really want to use a single-array, you can convert cell 0-99 to x,y like this:

```
var cell=50;

var cellWidth=10;

var y=cell/cellWidth;

var x=cell-y*cellWidth;
```

...And convert x,y to cell 0-99 like this:

```
var cell=y*cellWidth+x;
```